# Need help using pointers in order to traverse a C string in AVR Assembly atmega2560

Tags: string, pointers, assembly, avr, lcd

I am trying to print to an LCD screen a string defined in cseg by:

```
msg1_p: .db "This is the first message displayed on the first line of the lcd", 0
```

I am then trying to simulate movement of the text to the left off of the LCD. So far I am able to print the string the LCD and now I believe I need to iterate through this string, returning the address in memory in order to pass that to my display function. The display subroutine takes a 2 byte address in memory in order to print it starting from that address. Here is what it looks like:

```
ldi r16, high(msg1)
push r16
ldi r16, low(msg1)
push r16
call lcd_puts ;this function is used for writing to the board
pop r16
pop r16
```

So here are my thoughts on how to iterate the pointer.

First I used a defined pointer called msg1ptr and called

```
ldi XL, low(msg1ptr)            ;pointers to pointer
ldi XH, high(msg1ptr)
```

then I store the address of msg1 in data memory, which I wrote the string into earlier.

```
ldi r17, low(msg1)
ldi r16, high(msg1)
```

now I load the high and low bytes into the X pointer.

```
st X+, r17          ;load low msg1ptr 
st X, r16
```

I now have msg1ptr pointing at the beginning of the string right?

Now I am unsure how I can increment my pointers in order to move to the next space in memory. Basically how do I load the value of msg1 + 1.

My thoughts were to have another pointer that points to X and then use adiw command or something. To be honest im quite lost and any help would be super appreciated.